# ROW_NUMBER() fails when table is too big

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, row-number

I am working with Bigquery and I need to use ROW_NUMBER() in order to get only the first row which matches some condition.

Example:

```
select *except(rn)
from (
SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by timedate desc) AS rn
FROM
 table
)
where rn = 1
```

However, the query will fail because table is too big. How can I apply such logic without running out of resources?

Comment: What if you specify a [`LIMIT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit-clause-and-offset-clause) clause in the inner select of your derived table.  If it is bigger than the number of rows you are hoping to select from the outer query, then that could work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY timedate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id
```

You can test, play above with dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 2 timedate, 3 z UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,4,5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,6,7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,8,9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 10, 11
)
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY timedate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id
```

result is

```
Row id  timedate    z    
1   1   6           7    
2   2   10          11
```